# Display photos fetched from fql query from facebook in listview

Tags: android, facebook

I am using

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid  FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me());
```

to fetch photos of my facebook account. I have no idea to set the result in listview and json and bitmap. Can anybody tell me how to display this result.

Thanks in advance.